# How to get exactly models field after I filtered the models object?

Tags: python, django

It's hard to describe what I want to do, but I'll try.  After I have filtered the models like this ( I maximum could get only 1 object):

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(user__iexact=username) # username variable I got from URL
```

I want to show, which user wrote that tweet. So I am trying to do this in my templates like this:

```
<h1>{{tweets.username}}</h1>
```

However, it is not showing anything. By the way, it's my models:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

Comment: `username` is a property of a Tweet instance. It won't be available on a queryset of tweets; which one would it show? The first one? Fifth one? Why not just pass in the `username` from the view?

Comment: In your query you filter the Tweet objects with certain value for the attribute `user`. But the class Tweet has no attribute `user`. Should it be maybe `username__iexact=username`?

Comment: If he wants to get only one entry (and if returning only one entry is possible) then is better to use `get`. Otherwise if there are many possibilities you can also iterate through the tweets: `{% for tweet in tweets %}{{ tweet.username }}{% endfor %}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying a unique entry, use **.get**

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
```

instead of **.filter**.
The filter() method will return an array, even if it is only one result.

And also, your query is wrong... You have **username** on your model, not **user**

```
(username__iexact=username)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your Tweets as such:

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)
```

If you only want one Tweet back:

```
tweet = Tweet.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
```

Which tweet instance is returned would depend on the default ordering of the model, which is `id` unless you specify it in the model's `Meta` options.

In the template, you need to either loop over the tweets returned to display `tweet.username` which only exists on an instance, or you need to pass in the username and just display:

```
<h1>{{ username }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tweet model described above does not have any field user so the filter user__iexact will not work.

Assuming username is not unique as the model does not describe the username field to be unique

This can be changed as:
tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)

The filter queries always returns a list of objects.
TO access the first object use tweets[0]

to show the username we can use tweets[0].username